# Динамические массивы в СИ

Tags: c

Не могу разобратся с динамическими массивами. 
Делаю динамический массив, с произвольным индексом, так -

```
typedef struct
{
   int offset;
   int len;
}student;

struct student **students = NULL;

students[5000] = (student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
students[5000]->offset = 1; // здесь пишет dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
students[5000]->len = 2;

students[14] = (student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
students[14]->offset = 10;
students[14]->len = 20;
```

Понимаю, что тут не хватает ещё выделения памяти для самих students, как написать не знаю. WinXP, DevCPP (mingw?)
Количество элементов в students заранее неизвестно, и они могут идти не последовательно.

**UPDATE:** Вот рабочий код

```
typedef struct
{
    int offset;
    int len;
}student;

student* students = malloc(5000 * sizeof(student));

students[4999].offset = 1;
students[4999].len = 2;

students[14].offset = 10;
students[14].len = 20;

printf("%d",students[4999].len);
```

**UPD #2:**
Вот очень хороший модуль **[uthash](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/userguide.html#_a_hash_in_c)** для хеш массивов. Отличная и понятная документация, множество примеров.

Ещё хочу попробовать [Красночерные деревья](http://web.mit.edu/~emin/www.old/source_code/red_black_tree/index.html) от MIT

Comment: Попробуйте

    struct student **students = (struct student **)malloc(N * sizeof(struct student *));

(N — желаемый размер массива).

Comment: я не знаю сколько у меня будет изначально записей

Comment: @cromax, если интересно - можете поглядеть [здесь нечто похожее](http://hashcode.ru/questions/16650).

Не уверен, что Вы именно это имеете в виду, но полтора года назад уже решали на  ХэшКоде  чем-то похожую задачку.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрел, похожая ситуация. 
но зачем же так мучатся, если есть бинарные деревья )

Comment: @cromax, Вы не поняли разницу?

Бинарное дерево обеспечивает операции за O(log N), а там речь об **O(1)**.

Вот в этом-то все дело. 

--

В Вашем случае скорее всего стандартная библиотечная функция из `<search/h>` для работы с деревом `tsearch` (и ее "компаньоны" см. в `man tsearch`) вполне подойдет.

Правда, если понадобиться перебирать диапазон, начиная с найденного элемента, то придется писать аналог самому. За основу можно взять в сети Си код RB-дерева от MIT.

Comment: Если дерево строить не по ключам, а по битам этих ключей. Допустим, максимальная длинна ключа 32 бита, то время будет постоянным - для каждого ключа придется делать 32 операции перехода по дереву. Это не очень рациаонально, но как вариант. Не знаю на сколько я прав, но кажется что это верно )

Посмотрел примеры tsearch, бинарное дерево подходит, но выбор по индексу массива всетаки кажется не очень быстрый будет

Мб. быстрее использовать хеш массивы?
Для задачи, критично время выборки по индексу, и время добавления новых записей в массив?

Comment: @cromax, я правильно понимаю, что у Вас не реально горящая задача, а простое человеческое любопытство?

Вот и попробуйте разные варианты, посчитайте память и время исполнения для разных наборов тестовых данных.

Потом можете опубликовать это здесь, в разделе "исследования" (и получить кучу очков (может быть)).

Comment: Спасибо за советы!
Идея о тесте хорошая, счас этим и займусь )
Отпишу о результатах )

Comment: У вас тут выход за границы массива, не забывайте, что в С элементы нумеруются с нуля и последним индексом будет 4999!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Что за страшное `students[5000]`? =) В своём коде вы *дословно* пытаетесь присвоить 5001-му элементу массива `students` (который равен `NULL`), указатель на область памяти, достаточной для одного экземпляра структуры `student`.

Если вам нужно выделить память под 5000 записей типа `student`, то сделать это можно так:

```
students = (student**)malloc(5000 * sizeof(student));
```

И после завершения работы с данными **не забудьте очистить память** во избежение утечек!

```
free(students);
```

**UPDATE.**

Если вам нужно некое поле-челочисленный идентификатор студента, выделите в структуре дополнительную поле под этот идентификатор, а студента с 5000 ID ищите перебором по этому полю. Иначе вам придётся либо выделять память под всех студентов, либо реализовывать **хэш-таблицы** или другие способы поиска по ключу.

То, что вы хотите сделать на самом деле не имеет *никакого смысла* если задуматься, **как** компьютер производит доступ к элементу массива. Если у вас не выделена память под предыдущие элементы, как ему узнать, в какой ячейке искать 5000? А если вам нужно добавить 3000, а память между 0 элементом и 5000 уже занята? Именно поэтому язык не допускает таких трюков.

Comment: students[5000] это такой индекс, надо мне будет запись 5000, я ее смогу быстро достать.
при этом предыдущих 4999 записей может не быть.
*тоесть массив может быть фрагментирован

Comment: @cromax, в том и смысл динамического выделения памяти. Вы её выделяете по мере необходимости.

Обновил ответ.

Comment: да, придется тогда использовать хешь таблицы, т.к. искать перебором не подходит.

Comment: >при этом предыдущих 4999 записей может не быть. *тоесть массив может быть фрагментирован

IMHO, это как раз тот случай, когда массив вам не нужен. Либо хэш, где ключ - "номер", либо список, в котором одно из полей элемента будет вашим номером. Массивы в такой ситуации использовать просто нерационально.

Comment: Куда смотреть, мб какая библиотека, с хорошими примерами. 
только c, не с++; 
у хешь массивов время добавления одинаковое?

Comment: @cromax, реализаций хэшей на C много, выгугливаются без проблем, выбирать можно что больше нравится. Вплоть до hcreate/hsearch из libc. Время работы с элементами может быть разное, зависит от реализации. В любом случае больше, чем с массивами, конечно. Но я сомневаюсь, что именно это будет bottleneck, и в любом случае в хэшах больше смысла, чем в вашем кошмаре с пустотами в массивах.

Comment: @klopp, как Вы представляете себе последовательный перебор хэша?

Впрочем, для ключей, которыми являются числа (индексы массива) из *разумно ограниченного* диапазона это не большая проблема.

--

Другой вопрос это то, что количество хранимых в хэше записей надо знать заранее, поскольку при расширении хэша нам придется на какой-то момент прилично увеличивать расход памяти (старый и новый хэши будут совместно "жить" при рехэшировании).

Если же Вы предлагаете (без рехэширования) хэш со списками коллизий и фиксированным их максимумом, то производительность будет стремиться от O(1) к O(N).